# ploting a bar plot for large amount of data

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a 752 data points which i need to plot,
    I have plotted the data on bar plot using seaborn library in python , but graph i get is very unclear and I am not able to analyze anything through graph , is there any way i can view this graph more clearly and all data points fit with labels seen clearly in python

￼￼￼[image]

code  written is following

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
ax = sns.barplot(x="Events", y = "Count" , data = Unique_Complaints)
```

Comment: what is on your x axis?

Comment: you should use pandas library

Comment: I have not tried it, but will replacing the metric y with percentage of the frequency of the event type against the total events rounded to the nearest integer or decimal make the graph more visible? Then the range of values in y will be from 0 to 100 instead from 0 to 70000. This rounding of course will overestimate some of the types with very Low frequency. In that case, I would split the event types into two categories: high frequency and Low frequency in order to get a more clear view. Otherwise, if the visualisation is not optimised, I would suggest the solutions others provided in here.

Answer (score 5):

It is always difficult to visualise so many points. Nihal, has rightly pointed that it is best to use Pandas and statistical analysis to extract information from your data. Having said this, IDEs like Spyder and Pycharm and packages like Bokeh allow interactive plots where you can zoom to different parts of the plot. Here is an example with Pycharm:

## Code:

```
    # Import libraries
    import seaborn as sns
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Exponential decay function
    x = np.arange(1,10, 0.1)
    A = 7000
    y = A*np.exp(-x)

    # Plot the exponential function
    sns.barplot(x = x, y = y)
    plt.show()
```

## Figure without magnification

[image]

## Magnified figure

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To see a large amount of data you can use the `figure` from `matplotlib.pyplot` like this

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
figure(num=None, figsize=(20,18), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='r')
sns.barplot(x="Events", y = "Count" , data = Unique_Complaints)
plt.show()
```

I am using this to see a graph with 49 variables and the result is:[image]

My code is

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
figure(num=None, figsize=(20,18), dpi=256, facecolor='w', edgecolor='r')
plt.title("Missing Value Prercentage")
sns.barplot(miss_val_per, df.columns)
plt.show()
```

Data I am using is:
https://www.kaggle.com/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents

Answer (score 0):

**just swap x and y and try to increase the fig size**

Answer (score 0):

Similar idea to KRKirov, but even without an IDE, you can create an interactive plot as an `.html` file and examine it/share with colleagues using `plotly`.

Here is an example from their documentation:

```py
import plotly.express as px
data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
fig.show()
```

Full graph
[image]

Zoomed in version
[image]